# replace text in html with value from controller with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, text

I want to replace text in html with a value from a controller 
The original text string is image.name, which is the image title
Via a click event from the 'GoToImage' controller, the span should replace the
image.name with newName
Now, it only adds the newName, but doesn't replace the image.name

Markup:

```
<div data-ng-controller="GoToImage"> 
<span data-ng-model="newName">
{{image.name}}
{{newName}}
</span>
</div>
```

the controller:

```
.controller('GoToImage', function ($scope) {
      $scope.newName = {};
      $scope.newDescription = {};
      $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
      $scope.setImage = function(index) {
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;
        $scope.newName = $scope.series.images[index].name;
        $scope.newDescription = $scope.series.images[index].description;
      }
  });
```

also, I cannot get rid of the {} signs which show by default before the click event is fired

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try creating a new property that returns the current value that should be used.

```
$scope.nameDisplay = image.name
```

Then later in your code you can update the `nameDisplay` property to the value of `newName` and your UI can just bind to  `{{nameDisplay}}`.